# Vertically center all table row elements in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I can't seem to vertically align all the different types of elements in my Bootstrap table row.  I want the "select" dropdown, description text and button to all appear vertically centered. What do I need to do to fix this?

[image: what it looks like]

Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>testing...</title>
    <style>
        td {
            height: 1em;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="margin-left: 0px">    
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <colgroup>
                <col span="1" style="width: 4em">
                <col span="1" style="width: 15em">
                <col span="1" style="width: 4em">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
            <tr scope="row"><td>
                    <select class="form-control" id="qty">
                      <option>0</option>
                      <option>1</option>
                      <option>2</option>
                      <option>3</option>
                    </select>
            </td><td>Apples</td><td>10lb</td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add</button></td></tr>        
    </table>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `vertical-align:middle` to .table class table data.

```
    .table td {
        height: 1em;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
  <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <title>testing...</title>
     <style>
      .table td {
          height: 1em;
       vertical-align: middle;
      }
     </style>
      </head>
      <body>
     <div style="margin-left: 0px">   
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
      <colgroup>
        <col span="1" style="width: 4em">
        <col span="1" style="width: 15em">
        <col span="1" style="width: 4em">
      </colgroup>
      <tbody>
       <tr scope="row">
                <td>
            <select class="form-control" id="qty">
              <option>0</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
            </select>
       </td>
                <td>Apples</td>
                <td>10lb</td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add</button></td>
                </tr>     
     </table></div>
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Solution 2: you can also use !important to override the css properties.

```
td {
     height: 1em;
     vertical-align: middle !important;
        }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>testing...</title>
  <style>
    td {
      height: 1em;
      vertical-align: middle !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="margin-left: 0px">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
      <colgroup>
        <col span="1" style="width: 4em">
        <col span="1" style="width: 15em">
        <col span="1" style="width: 4em">
      </colgroup>
      <tbody>
        <tr scope="row">
          <td>
            <select class="form-control" id="qty">
              <option>0</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>Apples</td>
          <td>10lb</td>
          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Solution 3: using bootstrap add `align-middle` class to td.

```
<tr scope="row">
            <td class="align-middle">
                    <select class="form-control" id="qty">
                      <option>0</option>
                      <option>1</option>
                      <option>2</option>
                      <option>3</option>
                    </select>
            </td>
            <td  class="align-middle">Apples</td>
            <td  class="align-middle">10lb</td>
            <td  class="align-middle"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add</button></td>
            </tr>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <title>testing...</title>
     <style>
       td {
          height: 1em;
      }
     </style>
      </head>
      <body>
     <div style="margin-left: 0px">   
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
      <colgroup>
        <col span="1" style="width: 4em">
        <col span="1" style="width: 15em">
        <col span="1" style="width: 4em">
      </colgroup>
      <tbody>
       <tr scope="row">
                <td class="align-middle">
            <select class="form-control" id="qty">
              <option>0</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
            </select>
       </td>
                <td  class="align-middle">Apples</td>
                <td  class="align-middle">10lb</td>
                <td  class="align-middle"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add</button></td>
                </tr>     
     </table>
      </div>
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" **row**>
        <colgroup>
                <col span="1" style="width: 4em">
                <col span="1" style="width: 15em">
                <col span="1" style="width: 4em">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
            <tr scope="row"><td>
                    <select class="form-control" id="qty">
                      <option>0</option>
                      <option>1</option>
                      <option>2</option>
                      <option>3</option>
                    </select>
            </td><td>Apples</td><td>10lb</td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add</button></td></tr>        
</table>
```